# Android: Didn't find class "com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, daydream

There are three parts of this issue:

1. New Unity GoogleVR package appeared so I decided to update it. After deleting old package and importing new one, I got a suggestion to delete 4 files which are using old api.
2. If I delete them Android app crashes on mobile phone with an error 
   `Didn't find class "com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity"`. Note: one of the files it suggested to delete was `/Assets/Plugins/Android/unitygvractivity.aar` which I assume has some significants.
3. If I don't delete it, Unity can't build the package: `"unable to convert classes into dex format"`

My question: how to include GoogleUnityActivity class so Unity doesn't complain. And why would Unity delete this class?

I'm using:

- Unity3D 5.4.1f1-GVR7
- Latest GoogleVR package (Sep 23rd)
- JDK: jdk1.8.0_102
- SDK: 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause!

After I updated GoogleVR asset folder, I forgot there's another one called Plugins. That folder contains manifest.xml files which defines which class to use. After completely reimporting the asset, problem solved it self!

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the new "Google VR SDK for Unity v1.0" release marks the debut of **native Daydream integration in Unity**, then you don't need manually add "*`unitygvractivity.aar`*" to Android lib for building unity plugin anymore.

- use `extends UnityPlayerActivity` to instead of your original script.
- then back to Unity, choose add "Cardboard" in "Virtual Reality SDKs".
- check your AndroidManifest.xml, to see "`android:name="CompanyName.ProductName.xxxActivity"`" and "`user-permission`" are setting up correctly.

It should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Android app crashes after starting on the mobile, with the error `Didn't find class "com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity"`.

My solution was to delete the "Assets/Plugins" folder in Unity, and re-import the Google VR Package. When the re-import options screen appears, make sure you check the "Plugins" folder so the deleted "Assets/Plugins" folder can be re-imported.

The re-import recreates the incorrect AndroidManifest.xml files in Assets/Plugins/Android/ , and fixed my issue.

Comment: Similar problem, wondering how to implement this solution though.  I can delete the folders easily enough, but how to re-import the package?  I'm using the Unity beta build with Cardboard support baked in.